# Used Model Class method to order results, now .map returns 'undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, dictionary

I have a parent > child model relationship which is working fine using:

```
has_many :children, class_name: "Category", foreign_key: "parent_id"
belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Category"
```

in the model definition, but the order of the categories are not ordered in the way that I'd like, which is "parent, child, child, parent, child, child".

To achieve this result I started by making a simple example to sort the items correctly and got this working:

```
Category = Struct.new(:id, :title, :parent_id, :gender_id, :size_type_id)

categories = [
    Category.new(96, "Child 1 of 1", 99, 3, 1),
    Category.new(97, "Child 2 of 1", 99, 3, 1),
    Category.new(98, "Child 3 of 1", 99, 3, 1),
    Category.new(102, "Parent 2", nil, 3, 1),
    Category.new(100, "Child 1 of 2", 102, 3, 1),
    Category.new(99, "Parent 1", nil, 3, 1)
]

def order_categories (categories)
    final_categories = Hash.new

    sorted_categories = categories.sort_by{ |c| c[:id] }
    grouped_categories = sorted_categories.group_by{ |c| c.parent_id }

    grouped_categories[nil].each do |category|
        final_categories[category] = grouped_categories[category.id]
    end

    flattened_categories = final_categories.flatten(2)
    flattened_categories
end

order_categories(categories).map { |category| category.id }
```

This gives me an array of categories in the order I want `[99, 96, 97, 98, 102, 100]` though I feel that there must be a better way of doing this.

My main problem though is that when I actually use this approach in my Rails application as a model class then calling

```
.map { |category| category.id }
```

in my view template it no longer works.

I need to do this to populate a dropdown select menu in the correct order using the `grouped_options_for_select` helper.

For example in the `models/categories.rb`:

```
def self.ordered_grouped_parent
    final_categories = Hash.new

    sorted_categories = Category.all.sort_by{ |c| c[:id] }
    grouped_categories = sorted_categories.group_by{ |c| c.parent_id }

    grouped_categories[nil].each do |category|
      final_categories[category] = grouped_categories[category.id]
    end

    flattened_categories = final_categories.flatten(2)
    flattened_categories
end
```

and in the `controllers/items_controller.rb` there are two different instance variables:

```
@categories = Category.all
@ordered_categories = Category.ordered_grouped_parent
```

and in the `view/items/_form.html.erb` using them with `.map`:

```
<%= @categories.map{ |category| category.id } %> #works
<%= @ordered_categories.map{ |category| category.id } %> #error
```

The error given is `undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass` but if I inspect the `@ordered_categories` variable then it looks identical to `@categories`.

I'd really appreciate any insight into why this is happening, or what a better way would be to achieve this.

Comment: one of your `@ordered_categories` is probably 'nil'. Try using `compact`

Comment: that was it! a million thanks yous - how can I mark this post as the correct answer?

Comment: I ll post it as an asnwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your @ordered_categories is probably 'nil'. Try using `compact`

```
@ordered_categories = Category.ordered_grouped_parent.compact
```